# setState is too laggy in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use `pdf-lib`(JS library) in my React project. I am doing heavy work with the library with `async/await` and would like to update progress bar by updating state. Even though I call `setState` in `setTimeout`, the state is updated after the heavy work ends. So the progress bar shows only 0% and 100%. Could you kindly figure it out? I can't share my code, but if you want, I will show a little.

Comment: Not familiar with the library, but depending on how it's implemented, it might be possible. Share your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that "asynchronous" does *not* mean it runs "in parallel". It just means that code gets to run "out of order" in a controlled fashion.

Your page thread is just a single thread, so if you have a long-running function, you can mark that function as `async` or run it with `setTimeout` as much as you like but while your function code runs, *nothing else gets to run* (although in the case of `async`: only until the code hits an `await`, which I'm assuming pdf-kit does not use).

If you need to do heavy lifting, use a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), which is a special API for exactly this thing, running heavy workloads in a separate thread so that you don't block the main page thread.